# Tkinter: How to bind a Shift

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, key-bindings

I'm making a menubar in Tkinter with an accelerator:

```py
menubar = tk.Menu(window)
file_menu = tk.Menu(menubar)
menubar.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file_menu)
window.config(menu=menubar)

file_menu.add_command(label='Open resource pack', command=openPack, accelerator='Cmd+o' if IS_MAC else 'Ctrl+o')
window.bind_all('<M1-o>' if IS_MAC else '<Control-o>', openPack)

file_menu.add_command(label='Copy original pack', command=copyOriginalPack, accelerator='Shift+Cmd+c' if IS_MAC else 'Shift+Ctrl+c')
window.bind_all('<M1-C>' if IS_MAC else '<Control-C>', copyOriginalPack)
```

But for the `Copy original pack` option the key combination is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. The accelerator only shows the key combination in the menubar but doesn't actually run the command, so I have to manually bind to the window.

If I remember correctly, to bind <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> I just need to say `Control+C` and make the C uppercase because of <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

But I can't bind <kbd>Shift</kbd>. It works if I click the menu option, but the key combo doesn't. It works for the other option, which doesn't have <kbd>Shift</kbd>

Comment: Do you want to bind Shift alone or Shift+c? In the latter case, it is simply C ("c" capital).

Comment: @DYZ I want to bind Shift + Cmd + C (or Shift + Ctrl + C on other platforms)

Comment: Shift+c is simply "C capital." You should bind Ctrl + C.

Comment: But that's what I did. I binded `Control + C` or `Command + C` on macOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by writing `<M1-Shift-c>` (note the lowercase c)